# FIFO queue: how it works? queueless?

Tags: fpga, fifo

I study FIFO by myself using tutorials and lectures which are available (free access). Currently I am reading about FIFO queue. I have read , it provide a way to ensure messages are delivered in-order and exactly-once. Queue can order by arrival.

1. In any sources was not described ( explained ) how exactly FIFO queue works and can be implemented?

FIFO is first input first output, as I understood it means already FIFO delivers one by one, isnt? What does "queue" do? The same algorithm?

2. Is it an additional port in FIFO block or another block?

FIFO block has 4 main ports: data input, clk, reset, request. Is it queue a port as well?

3. Can be FIFO queueless?

Comment: Are you familiar with shift registers? They can be used as  FIFO.

Comment: Can you plrease change your title to actually describe the question? Can you also try to ask exactly **1** question in a question? Pick the one you need answered first, please. Then explain your question in more detail - we don't know what you know, or don't know.

Answer (score 0):

A FIFO is a form of a queue. So you can't have the FIFO without the queue.

How does a FIFO work? It depends on the actual implementation. One implementation is to have a block of memory and two counters - to keep track of the head and tail along with some comparison logic to determine if the queue is empty.

In software you might have an array and again variables to keep track of the head and tail and some code to determine if the queue is empty.

You refer to a 'fifo block' - are you referring to an implementation in an FGPA? You might want to be more explicit. Some FPGA have native blocks to do this, others might require a ram block and some logic or worst case, implemented using a number of LUTs.